# What does the residuals effectively mean in this model?

Tags: regression, linear-model, model

I'm doing sme test using R and linear models.

This is the code I'm using:

```
> a
[1] 0.10 0.05 0.02 0.04 0.09 0.05
> b
[1] 0.07 0.02 0.08 0.02 0.01 0.06
> c
[1] 0.03 0.03 0.01 0.05 0.06 0.09
> 
> r.a
[1] 0.10 0.15 0.17 0.21 0.30 0.35
> r.b
[1] 0.07 0.09 0.17 0.19 0.20 0.26
> r.c
[1] 0.03 0.06 0.07 0.12 0.18 0.27
> 
> mod = lm(r.a ~ r.b + r.c + 0)
> 
> mod

Call:
lm(formula = r.a ~ r.b + r.c + 0)

Coefficients:
   r.b     r.c  
0.8764  0.5231  

> mod$residuals
          1           2           3           4           5           6 
 0.02295527  0.03973251 -0.01561396 -0.01929937  0.03054829 -0.01912000 
> 
> mean(mod$residuals)
[1] 0.006533791
```

The three serie above (**a, b, c**) are the returns of three stocks, and `r.a, r.b, r.c` are the cumulative returns `cumsum(a) cumsum(b) cumsum(c)`

Now, as you can see I have used the `lm` function to calculate the linear model, at the end of the code there are the residuals of this linear model. I need to understand what those number effectively mean. In other words... I used the returns of these three serie, so are the residuals the difference of the percentage of return ?

I try to exlpain in with an example:

Take a look at the third value of each series(cumulative returns)

Example:

```
r.a[3] - 0.17
r.b[3] - 0.17
r.c[3] - 0.07
```

And the third residual is: **-0.01561396**

Does it mean that there is a variation of 1% ? (`0.01 = 1%   0.1 = 10%   1 = 100%`)

And the second question is:

What is the relathionship between the residuals and the mean of the residuals?

Example: 
- the third residual is: **-0.01561396**
- the mean is 0.006533791

Can I say THIS (third) residual is around 1% far from the mean? 
With this I mean...IF those three stocks(the returns of those three stocks) are moving and the spread goes to (~0.006533791) the total return of this movement is 1% ?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't quite understand what is going on here, so won't post an "answer".  But I think the answer to your first question "are the residuals the difference of the percentage of return" is "no".  I suggest you have a re-think of what your model is doing - looking to see if there is a linear relationship between the cumulative sum of the return on one stock and the cumulative sum of the returns on two others.  I don't think this is anything at all to do with what your questions are asking so you will probably want to go back to square one.

Comment: @PeterEllis thank you for the comment. I need to study the relathionship of two stocks, but AFTER checking the residuals I need to know what is the distance from their mean, I only know the residuals (this is the only data i have) and now i need to calculate How far is the mean from thei relathionship...

Comment: if all you have is the residuals from this particular model, I doubt you can find out much of interest.

Comment: Also, don't you have three stocks, not two?

Comment: @PeterEllis yes i have three stocks....and from residuals i need to calculate how much (%) is far form the mean(residuals)

Comment: I think you still need to clarify your question.  Surely the mean(residuals) will be zero by definition from the OLS method of calculation.  So any individual residual will be infinitely different from it.

Comment: ah, I just spotted that you deleted the intercept from your model, which is why mean(residuals) isn't zero.  I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve and I think you need a rethink.